# How to use LIKE operator in Sheetrock

Tags: javascript, html, sql, google-sheets, sheetrock

I'm trying to call the Javascript variable elem after LIKE in the SQL statement so that the input text is used there. However the way I'm doing it doesn't work with the Sheetrock library I'm using (http://chriszarate.github.io/sheetrock/).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Enter Tracking Code: <input type="text" id="textbox_id">
<input type="button" value="Submit">

<table id="switch-hitters" class="table table-condensed table-striped"></table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-sheetrock/1.0.1/dist/sheetrock.min.js"></script>


<script>

var mySpreadsheet = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_1elTo5zH1ew6KPYwoWtixX9hzFc8oxdRy5A0LWFkwg/edit#gid=0';
var elem =  document.getElementById('textbox_id').value;
$('#switch-hitters').sheetrock({
    url: mySpreadsheet,
    query: "select A,B,C,D,E where A LIKE %"+elem+"%"
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you updated your question here is updated answer. Check working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r0sk7vtf/

- you need to handle submit button click event and then call service
- while spreadsheet api understand like without quotes, it doesn't work via sheetrock.js , so you need to use `A like '9999%'` in your query

Snippet:

```
var mySpreadsheet = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_1elTo5zH1ew6KPYwoWtixX9hzFc8oxdRy5A0LWFkwg/edit#gid=0';

var button = $('#btn'), elem = $('#textbox_id')

button.on('click', function(e){ 
  var v =  elem.val();
  $('#switch-hitters').sheetrock({
    url: mySpreadsheet,
    query: "select A,B,C,D,E where A like '" + v + "%'"
  });
 })
```

Comment: This didn't work when I tested it - when I press the "Submit" button after typing in numbers, nothing aside from the column headers from the sheet shows up.

Comment: Do you mean the input expression? No, I want the user to be able to just type in numbers (a "tracking code"), and have the output be all of the rows that have that number in column A

Comment: Can you show me what that would look like in query?

Comment: I made the above changes by adding % on left and right. But still the input bar doesn't do anything when I type in the numerical values and press Submit

Comment: I'm using the Sheetrock library, i.e. $('#switch-hitters').sheetrock({ -- no sherlock

Comment: The code above is everything I have. Still doesn't work